# How to swap elements in different list and different size Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, swap

I have a dataframe df1. The dataframe has one column named 'Path'. Each row has a list. They are like this:

```
Path                   
____________________
[OAK, PHX, MIA, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, LAS, ORD, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
...
```

I wish to swap the **second** and **third** value of each odd row with the corresponding **second** and **third** values of the next row (even row), and then swap each pair individually. In the input example from above, the values `PHX, MIA` from the first row should be swapped with the values `SEA, FLL` from the second row, and then inverted.

```
Path                   
____________________
[OAK, PHX, MIA, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]   

# Swap 2nd and 3rd value between rows 

Path                   
____________________
[OAK, SEA, FLL, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, PHX, MIA, PBG]

# Swap 2nd and 3rd value in all rows
Path                   
____________________
[OAK, FLL, SEA, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, MIA, PHX, PBG]
```

The result should be something like this:

```
Path                   
____________________
[OAK, FLL, SEA, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, MIA, PHX, PBG]   
[OAK, FLL, DFW, FLL, PBG]   
[OAK, ORD, LAS, PBG]
....
```

How can I do it with Python?

Comment: on what basis you're changing lists?

Comment: You have not mentioned the logic for swapping!

Comment: I'm not following what you'd like to swap?

Comment: It is random, apart the first and the last

Comment: @LucaLazzati please update the question with the logic

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out = df['Path'].apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x)  )

dfLength = len(df)
if dfLength%2==0:
    oddIndex = list(range(0,dfLength-1, 2))
    evenIndex = list(range(1, dfLength,2))
else:
    oddIndex = list(range(0,dfLength, 2))
    evenIndex = list(range(1, dfLength,2))

#Swapping odd-even rows
oddData = out.iloc[oddIndex][[1,2]].copy() 
evenData = out.iloc[evenIndex][[1,2]].copy()

out.iloc[oddIndex, [1,2]] = evenData.values
out.iloc[evenIndex, [1,2]] = oddData.values

#Swapping columns 2 & 3
col2 = out.loc[:,1].copy()
col3 = out.loc[:,2].copy()

out.loc[:,1] = col3.values
out.loc[:,2] = col2.values
```

Final output would look like

```
     0    1    2    3    4
0  OAK  FLL  SEA  FLL  PBG
1  OAK  MIA  PHX  PBG  NaN
2  OAK  FLL  DFW  FLL  PBG
3  OAK  ORD  LAS  PBG  NaN
```

If you want the output as a list,

```
out.apply(lambda x : list(x.dropna().values), axis = 1)
```

```
0    [OAK, PHX, MIA, FLL, PBG]
1         [OAK, SEA, FLL, PBG]
2    [OAK, LAS, ORD, FLL, PBG]
3         [OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
4         [OAK, DFW, FLL, PBG]
```